# POST method did not send data to DB?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

So, have next problem. Everything work but, and i send my data to DB. But something went wrong.

My simple Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    private MessageService service;

    //public HomeController(MessageService service) {
    //  this.service = service;
    //}
    
    
    @GetMapping ("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index1";
    }
    
    @PostMapping ("/")
    public String saveSave(@ModelAttribute ("usermessage")UserMessage usermessage) {
        service.save(usermessage);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

My Service

```
public interface MessageService {
    
    UserMessage save(UserMessage usermessage);

}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messagerepo;

    @Override
    public UserMessage save(UserMessage usermessage) {
        return messagerepo.save(usermessage);
    }
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository <UserMessage, Long> {

}
```

Entity + getters + setters + empty constructor + constructor

```
@Entity
@Table (name ="UserMessage")
public class UserMessage {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column (name = "name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column (name = "mobile", length = 40, nullable = false)
    private String mobile;
    
    @Column (name ="email", length = 70)
    private String email;
    
    @Column (name="message", length = 1000)
    private String message;
```

And main element part of HTML page - > HTMl FORM..

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${usermessage}" method ="post" id="add-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" field="*{name}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше ім'я" required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" field="*{email}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваша почта" required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="mobile" field="*{mobile}" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш моб.телефон"
                                    required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" field="*{message}" placeholder="Суть питання"
                                    required="required"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn" id="btn" type="submit">Надіслати Запит</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Everything work good, but then i don't know. In my Db everything okey, because column with field id, name, email, mobile, message is present.

Comment: In controller saveSave method does usermessage have value? In MessageServiceImpl save method, does usermessage have value? You can start by printing usermessage in these methods to see where it's has value or not.